# How to give a LI item a color on mouseover?

Tags: javascript

I want to color the LI item on mouseover with javascript.
for the people who think i can use Css. You are right but for this one i need Javascript

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOM</title>

</head>
<body>

<p>An unordered list:</p>
<ul id='lijst'>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Thea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var list = document.getElementById('lijst');
        var y = list.getElementsByTagName('LI');
        list.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {

        });
      }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, when you move with your mouse over coffee or thea or milk. Than they will be orange. But i have no idea how.

Comment: Just use css [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: Your tag is wrong, should be [tag:css]! Please google a bit before asking (Just like the above comment suggested  `li:hover`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list
var y 

window.onload = function() {
        list = document.getElementById('lijst');
       y = list.getElementsByTagName('LI');
        for(var i = 0; i<y.length; i++){
        y[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
          this.style.color = 'blue'
        });
        y[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
          this.style.color = 'black'
        });
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOM</title>

</head>
<body>

<p>An unordered list:</p>
<ul id='lijst'>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Thea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>



<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

You don't need JS for this. This can be easily achieved by CSS

Comment: I know i can use css but it is an assignment for school and it has to be js

Answer (score 3):

- you can simply use `css` for this.

```css
.list li:hover {
    color : #FF0000
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li >Coffee</li>
    <li >Thea</li>
    <li >Milk</li>
</ul>
```

- you can use `javascript` like this

```js
function hoverList(list) {
  list.style.color = "#FF0000";
}
```

```html
    <ul class="list">
        <li onmouseover="hoverList(this)">Coffee</li>
        <li onmouseover="hoverList(this)">Thea</li>
        <li onmouseover="hoverList(this)">Milk</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Happy to help. i changes a answer because there were some js code in my css answer

Answer (score 0):

Have an error

```
var list = document.getElementById('lijst');
var y = x.getElementsByTagName('LI');
```

don't have x var, change to

```
var list = document.getElementById('lijst');
var y = list.getElementsByTagName('LI');
```

Comment: And, yes, you don't need js for this functionality. Css pseudoclass :hover for any element

Comment: Yeah, but i need js for this one

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to handle this task is to use the **hover** property of CSS. The code for that is

```
<style>
    li:hover{
     color: orange
            }        
 </style>
```

However, if you insist to use the mouseover property, you can by using the following way

```
<script>
        var li = document.getElementsByClassName("item-list");
        li[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
            this.style.color = "orange";
        });
        li[1].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            this.style.color = "orange";
        });
        li[2].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            this.style.color = "orange";
        });


    </script>
```